# Making Extension Compatible in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

Tried to install an extension that uses the following Enterprise feature: enterprise_admingws/role

This is the code that returns the error

```
$role = Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_admingws/role');
        if ($role->getIsAll()) {
            return true; // super admin is found
        }
```

what can be changed to make this work in Magento community 1.9.1

Comment: I think you need to check update log and check what updates required and follow those. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

First check the extension is installed or not properly, if its installed then check module if there is any other dependency of EE is not there, if its there then change that to use required information from community edition.

Hope this will help, Good Luck!!!